# 'Error 999999: Contact Esri Support Team' error message in relation to support vector machine? won't create the raster layer

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, error-999999

For some reason when I try to create a raster layer from the support vector machine it gives out the below error message, I have done lots of research as to why but I can't find anything that will help me with raster layers and this error in relation to the support vector machine? unsure if anyone else has had a similar issue before?
[image]

Comment: Please always provide error messages as formatted text rather than only in a picture.